# AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'guild' | discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Im making a bot that creates a new serverid.yml file when its invited to a server so the yml file will store all of the bot settings for that server. Apon trying to do so i get this error:

`AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'guild'`

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(server):
   dict_file = {"auto-mod" : "True"}
   serverId = server.guild.id
   with open(f"{serverId}.yml", 'w') as file:
      yaml.dump(dict_file, file)
```

Comment: Just remove .guild because server is already a guild?

Comment: Please don't create individual files for every guild. This is extremely wasteful in space and induces IO costs. Merge them into something larger, like a dict of every guild. (PS: `"True"` is unnecessary. You can set it to `True`, the boolean value)

Comment: i removed server from both the attributes in on_guild_join and on server.guild and now ity says `TypeError: on_guild_join() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: It should hopefully work when using `serverId = server.id`. It needs to stay in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
   dict_file = {"auto-mod" : "True"}
   serverId = guild.id
   with open(f"{serverId}.yml", 'w') as file:
      yaml.dump(dict_file, file)
```